# Generate bill on clicking a button in html

Tags: html

I am working on a project, in which needs generation of bill. what is the code for which if we click a button then it will print a hard-copy for the user

Comment: you can use <a href="thebill.pdf">button</a>

Comment: how much you have tried..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
```

you can obviously use `<a>` or `<input>` and put `onclick="window.print()"` in there

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using javascript...Try like this

```
<input type="button" value="Print This Page" onClick="window.print()" />
```